# AWK - sum particular fields after match

Tags: awk

I have a txt file that is 10s to hundreds lines long and and I need to sum a particular field each line ( and output) if a preceeding field matches.

Here is an example datset:

```
Sample4;6a0f64d2;size=1;,Sample4;f1cb4733a;size=6;,Sample3;aa44410feb29210c1156;size=2;
Sample2;5b91bef2329bd87f4c7;size=2;,Sample1;909cd4e2940f328b3;size=2;
```

The structure is

`<sample ID>;<random id>;size=<numeric>;,` then the next entry.  There could be hundreds of entries in a line (this is just a small example)

Basically, I want to sum the "size" numbers for each entry across a line (entries seperated by ',') , but only those that have match with a particular sample IDentifier (e.g. sample4 for example)
So, if we want to match just the 'Sample4's, the script would produce this-

```
awk '{some-code for sample4}' example.txt
7
0
```

Because the entries with 'Sample4' add up to 7 in line 1, but in line 2, there are no Sample4 entries matching.

This could be done for each "SampleID" or, ideally, done for all sample IDs provided in a list ( perhaps in simple file, 1 line per sample ID), which would then output the counts for each row, with each Sample ID having its own column - e.g. for the example file above, results of the script would be:

```
Sample1  Sample2  Sample3  Sample4
0        0        2        7  
2        2        0        0
```

Any ideas on how to get started?

Thanks!

Comment: If there can be 'hundreds of entries in a line' what is the logical function of a `\n`? Do separate lines mean anything?

Comment: each line corresponds to a different taxon or organism. So the goal of this script would be to sum/count occurances for a given sample ID for each line (taxon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

another `awk`

```
 awk -F';' '{for(i=1;i<NF-1;i+=3) 
               {split($(i+2),e,"="); 
                sub(/,/,"",$i); 
                header[$i]; 
                a[$i,NR]+=e[2]}} 
        END {for(h in header) printf "%s", h OFS; 
             print "";
             for(i=1;i<=NR;i++) 
               {for(h in header) printf "%s", a[h,i]+0 OFS;
                print ""}}' file | column -t


Sample1  Sample2  Sample3  Sample4
0        0        2        7
2        2        0        0
```

ps. the order of columns is not guaranteed.

**Explanation**
To simplify parsing I used `;` as the delimiter and got rid of `,` before the names.  Using the structure assign name=sum of values for each line using multi-dim array `a`, separately keep track of all names in the header array. Once the lines are consumed, in the END block print the header and for each line the value of the corresponding name (or 0 if missing).  Pretty print with `column -t`.

Comment: Awesome... Can you provide a quick explanation of what is going on there?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding this correctly, you can do:

```
$ awk '{split($0,samp,/,/)
      for (i=1; i in samp; i++){
        sub(/;$/, "", samp[i])
        split(samp[i], fields, /;/)
        split(fields[3], ns, /=/)
        data[fields[1]]+=ns[2]
     }
      printf "For line %s:\n", NR
      for (e in data)
           print e, data[e]
      split("", data)  
 }' file
```

Prints:

```
For line 1:
Sample3 2
Sample4 7
For line 2:
Sample1 2
Sample2 2
```